# llvm get called function name using llvm instruction

Tags: llvm

I want to know if an llvm::intruction is a function call and if so what is the name of the fucntion it is calling to.

Also is there a way to get llvm::CallInst from an llvm::Instruction?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Instruction* I = ...
if (isa<CallInst>(I)) {
  StringRef name = cast<CallInst>(I).getCalledFunction().getName();
  ...
}
```

For more information on this, see [the relevant section in LLVM Programmer's Manual](http://llvm.org/docs/ProgrammersManual.html#the-isa-cast-and-dyn-cast-templates). In general, I wholeheartedly recommend this guide for beginners.

Comment: Note that it only works for direct function calls

Answer (score 4):

[`Instruction`](http://llvm.org/docs/ProgrammersManual.html#the-instruction-class) is the common base class for all LLVM instructions.

[`CallInst`](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1CallInst.html) is a subclass of `Instruction` for call instructions.

If you have `Instruction *inst`, you can get a `CallInst` by

```
CallInst *ci = cast<CallInst>(inst);
```

Comment: Thank you. Now I see that Instruction.h is the base class for CallInst.

Comment: I got an error saying:  error: cannot convert ‘const llvm::CallInst’ to ‘llvm::CallInst*’ in initialization

Comment: @Kroka There was a small error in the answer. It is dynamic_cast that returns a pointer.

Answer (score 2):

Consequent use of `isa<>` and `cast<>`, as in the accepted answer, is **NOT A GOOD PRACTICE** according to [LLVM Programmer's Manual](https://llvm.org/docs/ProgrammersManual.html#the-isa-cast-and-dyn-cast-templates):

> Note that you should **not** use an `isa<>` test followed by a `cast<>`, for that use the `dyn_cast<>` operator.

Regarding `dyn_cast<>` the manual explains:

> The `dyn_cast<>` operator is a “checking cast” operation. It checks to see if the operand is of the specified type, and if so, returns a pointer to it (this operator does not work with references). If the operand is not of the correct type, a null pointer is returned. Thus, this works very much like the `dynamic_cast<>` operator in C++, and should be used in the same circumstances. Typically, the `dyn_cast<>` operator is used in an if statement or some other flow control statement.

Therefore, LLVM suggests to modify the accepted answer using `dyn_cast<>`:

```
Instruction I = ...
if (auto *CI = dyn_cast<CallInst>(&Inst)) {
     StringRef callee_name = CI->getCalledFunction()->getName();
     ...
}
```

In fact, this form of the if statement effectively combines together a call to `isa<>` and a call to `cast<>` into one statement, which is very convenient.

Note that `getCalledFunction()` resturns a `Function *`, so you should use `->` (not `.`) to call the member function `getName()`.